# MySqli Database connection access denied php

Tags: php, mysqli, connection

Hey I'm connecting to a DB in PHP like I normally would, the info is all there and correct.  Checked the password a few times.  Is there anything here that would ruin my connection? Here's my (nice and vague) error message:

Connection failed: Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' to database 'DB'

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
?>
<style>



</style>

<html>
    <body>

<?php   
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "DB";


// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your database user is "user" and not "root" and password is "password" ??

Comment: this is apart, but your style tag is out of html structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Connection failed: Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' to database 'DB'

Nope thats not vague, its as accurate as it can get. User `user` does not have permission to access Database `DB`  on `localhost` even if the password is correct. No if else or guesses or chances of it being incorrect in thinking so.

Look at database permissions for `DB`